# swapping divisible numbers and getting declared void error

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers

I am working on a program which would reverse all the given numbers that are divisible by a particular number.

For ex:
input = "13694097"
divisible number = 3;
Numbers that are divisible by 3 in the input are : 3,6,9,9. Hence the reverse shall be 9,9,6,3. If we replace that in the current array, then we get 
ouput = "19964037"

Here's, the code for the program. I am trying to build the prorgram but i keep getting the below error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int convert_to_int(char s) 
{
    return s - '0';   
}

void reverse_string(char *string, int length, int number) 
{

    char *start = string;
    char *end = string+length-1;

    while(true) 
    {

        while((convert_to_int(*start) % number) != 0) {
            start++;
        }

        while((convert_to_int(*end) % number) != 0) {
            end--;
        }

        if(start >= end)
            break;
        else
        {
            // Swap numbers 
            char temp = *start;
            *start = *end;
            *end = temp;
        }
    }

    return;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

    char input[] = "1253486794";

    void reverse_string(input, 10, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The error output:Compiling the source code....

```
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:45:24: error: variable or field 'reverse_string' declared void
    void reverse_string(input, 10, 3);
                    ^
```

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
void reverse_string(input, 10, 3);
```

to

```
reverse_string(input, 10, 3);
```